# unable to delete a file using os.remove()

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the end, the script is unable to delete a file throwing an error message like

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process:
>   'C:\Users\shruthi.sundaresan\Downloads\Sears_Auto_Center_Feedback.zip'.

Can anyone help delete the file?

This is the code I executed.

```
zfile = ZipFile("C:\\Users\\shruthi.sundaresan\\Downloads\\Sears_Auto_Center_Feedback.zip")
zfile.extractall(path = "C:\\Users\\shruthi.sundaresan\\Desktop\\extract")

time.sleep(20)
import os
os.remove("C:\\Users\\shruthi.sundaresan\\Downloads\\Auto_Center_Feedback.zip")
```

Comment: Close whatever else is using the file and then retry it.

Comment: strange, but the filenames are inconsistent.

Comment: yeah its a typo....but even tried with right filename, didn't work...the only application that used the .zip was winzip to extract the files and it successfully got extracted, but donno why it is showing the above message

Answer (score 4):

make sure it is closed.

```
with ZipFile(r"C:\...") as zfile:
    zfile.extractall(path = r"C:\...")
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the info.. We have not used read mode but we have failed to use the file close option. However your reply guided as in the right direction towards file permissions.